# Why does the RTE default to Media Library in the Document Manager?

Tags: richtext-editor

Sitecore 8.2 u6

When you edit the properties of a link in an RTE and attempt to change the link, the document manager defaults to `sitecore/media library`. Shouldn't it default to `sitecore`?

[image]

Changing the `\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\EditorPage.aspx` seems to have no effect, even after clearing the browser cache. It's also annoying having to modify this file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, the purpose of Document Manger is select media items you would like to link to. Thus the default location is the Media Library. You can refer to [sitecore documentation](http://ttps://doc.sitecore.com/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/insert-a-link-in-a-text-field.html).